# using curl in .NET

Tags: .net, curl

I need to make the following curl call from .NET and have no idea how to go about it since I am a newbie in this area.

curl -e http://www.example.com \'https://curlservice.com/find?v=1.0&q=myquery'

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have seen other examples with different curl arguments but am unable to figure out how to do it for the above command in .NET.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking us to provide a complete solution to a trivial task, and shows no own work by the OP.

Comment: Also note that calling `curl` to do something is probably a terrible idea - you might be better off using `libcurl.net` or perhaps even the simple `HttpClient` class etc.